Positive association preserved by log-supermodular "tilting" of density
$X$ is an associated random vector (with a well-defined probability density function $f$): That is, for any pair of coordinate-wise increasing functions $g$ and $h$,
$$Cov(g(X),h(X))\geq0.$$
I want to show that for any non-negative, log-supermodular function $u$, the random vector $Y$ whose density is
$$f_{Y}(x)=\frac{f(x)u(x)}{\mathbb{E}\left[u(X)\right]}$$
is also associated.
My intuition is that the log-supermodular transformation can only "reinforce" the positive association between the components of $X$. But I fail to see how to prove this. Any pointers appreciated.
